# How to transfer post from one component to another?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Good afternoon, please tell me. I am training now using Vuex and I cannot transfer the post from one component to another. I have a component Pagination, where all the posts and the history component are stored where and should send the first 5 posts that I click on to visit them. That is, it should work approximately as a history of viewing posts. I wrote some code here, but my posts are not displayed, tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

Component code where all posts are stored:

```
    <template>
  <div class = "app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(post, index) in paginatedData" class="post" :key="index">
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: post.id, title: post.title, body: post.body} }" @click="addPostToHistoryComp(post.id, post.title, post.body)">
        <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
        <p class="boldText"> {{ post.title }}</p>
        </router-link>
        <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
      </li>
      </ul>
        <div class="allpagination">
          <button type="button" @click="page -=1" v-if="page > 0" class="prev"><<</button>
          <div class="pagin">
            <button class="item"
            v-for="n in evenPosts"
            :key="n.id"
            v-bind:class="{'selected': current === n.id}"
            @click="page=n-1">{{ n }} </button>
          </div>
          <button type="button" @click="page +=1" class="next" v-if="page < evenPosts-1">>></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import {mapState} from 'vuex'
      export default {
        name: 'app',
        data () {
          return {
            current: null,
            page: 0,
            visiblePostID: '',
          }
        },
        mounted(){
          this.$store.dispatch('loadPosts')
        },
        computed: {
          posts(){
            return this.$store.state.posts
          },
          search(){
            return this.$store.state.sSearch
          },
          evenPosts: function(posts){
            return Math.ceil(this.posts.length/6);
          },
          paginatedData() {
            const start = this.page * 6;
            const end = start + 6;
            return this.filteredPosts.slice(start, end);
          },
          filteredPosts() {
            return this.posts.filter((post) => {
              return post.title.match(this.search);
            });
          },
        },
        methods: {
          addPostToHistoryComp(val){
            this.$store.dispatch('transforPostToHistoryComp', { // как вызвать actions с объект с параметром
              pTitle: val.post.title,
              pBody: val.post.body,
              pId: val.post.id
            })
          },
        }
      }
    </script>
```

The code of the History component where the last 5 posts that were opened should be displayed:

```
    <template>
  <div class="history">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(historyPost, index) in historyPosts" class="post" :key="index">        
        <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
        <p class="boldText"> {{ post.title }}</p>
        <p> {{ post.body }}</p>
      </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default{
    computed: {
      historyPosts(){
        return this.$store.state.historyPosts
      },
    },

  }
</script>
```

And the code of my story (Vuex):

```
    export default new vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: [],
    sSearch: '',
    title: '',
    body: '',
    id: Number,
    historyPosts: []
  },
  actions: {
    loadPosts ({commit}) {
      axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
        let posts = response.data
        commit('SET_POSTS', posts)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    },
    transforTitleAndBody({commit}, payload){ // мутация которая изменяет сосотаяние в sSearch
      const todo = {
        title: payload.sTitle,
        body: payload.sBody,
        id: payload.sId
      }
      axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', todo).then(_ => {
        commit('ADD_TODO', todo)
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
    },
    transforPostToHistoryComp({commit}, payload){ // мутация которая изменяет сосотаяние в sSearch
      const todohistory = {
        title: payload.pTitle,
        body: payload.pBody,
        id: payload.pId
      }
      commit('ADD_TODO_HISTORY', todohistory)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_POSTS(state, posts) {
      state.posts = posts
    },
    transforSearch(state, payload){ // мутация которая изменяет сосотаяние в sSearch
      state.sSearch = payload
    },
    ADD_TODO (state, todoObject) {
      state.posts.unshift(todoObject)
    },
    ADD_TODO_HISTORY (state, todohistoryObject) {
      state.historyPosts.unshift(todohistoryObject)
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Please, make some example of this. Maybe on jsfiddle, then we can take debug on it.

Comment: I have a full code in GitHub https://github.com/belichenk0andreyka/BlogVUEX

Comment: Okay, I'll take look on that soon

Comment: Agreed, I will wait for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what happening. You have some erros on code of the file Pagination.vue

You was putting @click under `<router-link>`, that doesn't work because router link change the page with preventing effect any other event before leave.

I made some changes on template and script. I think will work.

```
    <template>
  <div class="app">
    <ul>
      <template v-for="(post, index) in paginatedData">
        <li class="post" :key="index" @click="addPostToHistoryComp(post)">
          <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg">
          <p class="boldText">{{ post.title }}</p>
          <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
    <div class="allpagination">
      <button type="button" @click="page -=1" v-if="page > 0" class="prev"><<</button>
      <div class="pagin">
        <button
          class="item"
          v-for="n in evenPosts"
          :key="n.id"
          v-bind:class="{'selected': current === n.id}"
          @click="page=n-1"
        >{{ n }}</button>
      </div>
      <button type="button" @click="page +=1" class="next" v-if="page < evenPosts-1">>></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "app",
  data() {
    return {
      current: null,
      page: 0,
      visiblePostID: ""
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadPosts");
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.state.posts;
    },
    search() {
      return this.$store.state.sSearch;
    },
    evenPosts: function(posts) {
      return Math.ceil(this.posts.length / 6);
    },
    paginatedData() {
      const start = this.page * 6;
      const end = start + 6;
      return this.filteredPosts.slice(start, end);
    },
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.posts.filter(post => {
        return post.title.match(this.search);
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPostToHistoryComp(post) {
      this.$store.dispatch("transforPostToHistoryComp", {
        pTitle: post.title,
        pBody: post.body,
        pId: post.id
      });

      this.$router.push({
        name: "detail",
        params: { id: post.id, title: post.title, body: post.body }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I also have such a question, when the first post is added to the History component, it is displayed normally, but the second and all the following do not show pictures, what could be the problem?

Comment: On History file, change the path on <img src="src/assets/nature.jpg"> to: <img src="./assets/nature.jpg">

Comment: And why did this help?

Comment: Because you you are referring the path "src" inside of src and the dot indicates that you are inside of folder what you want like base path.

Comment: Thank you very much